# Please is there any way i can get access to a key  that matches a value selected on a dropdown in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am learning Javascript / React and I have been doing this react project to make memes and I have all the data regarding the memes in an array of objects but I am stuck now for days without getting it to do what I want.

Inside each object is a name with a value, an ID with a value, A blank with the image URLs. I want to display the names to the user in a dropdown and I want to get access to the ID and blank value of the selected name from the dropdown so that I can feed the image to the user.

I have tried extracting the names and the IDs into separate strings and check for a matching word but sometimes the string value of the ID is not even included in the string values of the name, so that didn't work at all and now I did it like a kind of a hack with a counter that increases each time the onChange function is called and I used the number to feed the image according to the index matching the number but this gives me the wrong image anytime that a user decides to choose image randomly. This may sound a bit abstract so I have included some screenshots here and my code with a link to a code sandbox where all the program lives and hoping to get the help that I need, please.

Hers is the Code Snippets;

```
export default function MyComponent() {

  const [bulkImageArray, setBulkImageArray] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState();
  const [imagesNames, setImagesNames] = useState();


  // This is the function that should get me access to the object id value when any value is selected.
  function handleChange(event) {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
    console.log('You just selected: ' + event.target.value);
    // setImagesNames(event.target.value);
    setImagesNames(bulkImageArray[counter].name);
    setImageUrls(bulkImageArray[counter].blank);

    console.log(typeof event.target.value);
  }

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={handleChange}>
          {bulkImageArray.map((item) => (
            <option key={item.id}>
              {/* {item.id} */}
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>

        <img src={imageUrls} alt={imagesNames} />

        <div>
          {bulkImageArray.map((item) => (
            <img
              style={{
                width: '400px',
                height: '400px',
                cursor: 'pointer',
              }}
              key={item.id}
              alt={item.name}
              src={item.blank}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

screenshots:

Array of Objects Structure: [image]

Single Object Structure: [image]

Function Tigered on select: [image]

The dropdown for users to select the image: [image]

I don't know if all this information is enough but this is the code sandbox to the complete project.

[image: Edit quirky-sara-9hh5y]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `value={item.id}` to your `option` and then just using that to get your image? `bulkImageArray.find(testItem => testItem.id === event.target.value)`

Another way would be to do `bulkImageArray.map((item, index) => ...option value={index}...` and then use it even more directly `bulkImageArray[event.target.value]`

Comment: Code in codesandbox doesn't match what you've shared here. Also, it doesn't seem to load.

Comment: I am sorry about the codeSandbox thing, I don't know why it didn't work and the code is different because after i took the screenshot i kept working on the same file. I wasn't thinking about using the value attribute in this case at all.. Thanks a lot for this input,, I appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `value={item.id}` to `option`, so that `select` `onChange` can select the value to `id`, then use the `id` to find the selected item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this input. it was starring right on my face but honestly i wouldn't have thought about it even if had spent another 20 hours starring on my screen. Thanks.,